# How to change the output file name in python in batch process?

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, loops, batch-processing

I am running a model in batchess. I have included my code below. 
I have 1000+ data files. Each time when I run the script I get the output for each input file, however the name of each output for every input comes as `OUTPUT.0001.nc`, where `nc` is an extension and `0001` is the number of iteration. If I will keep number of iteration 3, I will get output files as `OUTPUT.0001.nc, OUTPUT.0002.nc, OUTPUT.0003.nc`

Intially I wrote the script for quite lesser number of grids and did some manual stuff to analyse the result, but now I have to do the same things for 1000+ grids.

For lesser number of grids (say 12), I was running the code, saving the results of each file in a new folder having the same name as input file, and renaming them in last after deleting all the iteration results but last one.

However, since now the number is large, I need to change the output file name (same as input) through script after deleting all the iteration except the last one. 
**How to do this?**

input file = `1.dat`  output file= `1.nc` from `OUTPUT.0005.nc`

`OUTPUT.0000.nc` such name are created because of the model's code, I can't alter this.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import numpy as np
import os
import shutil
import glob

# Name of the current working directory
current_directory=os.getcwd()     

# Loop for creating the file name
for point in np.arange(1,101):   
  x=point 

  fname=str(x)+".dat"             

  if os.path.exists(fname):

    command="./driver.exe"+" "+str(fname)
    # Invoke command in the terminal
    os.system(command)  
    # create directories 
    directory=str(x)   
    os.makedirs(directory)  
    # path of created directory     
    destination = os.path.abspath(directory)
    # path of existing file
    source = os.path.abspath(fname)


    # Move all files with ".nc" extension to relevant directory
    files = glob.iglob(os.path.join(current_directory, "*.nc"))
    for file in files:
      if os.path.isfile(file):
        shutil.move(file, destination)

    # Move file which is used for execution in relevant directroy
    shutil.move(source, destination)
```

What I want to do is, run the model in batch

**Loop-1** will take input file `1.dat`
1. delete all the iteration output except the last one
2. Change the name of the output as per the input file name `1.nc`

**Loop-2** will take input file `2.dat`

Comment: How many input files are a you reading?  This code looks like you're reading only files 1.dat through 101.dat.

Comment: In this code I have 100 files which belongs to one grid, each file represent one sub grid. I have 35 grids, so the number will go upto 3500.

Comment: Your question isn't very clear. Are you asking how to delete files that you don't want? Are you asking how to modify the code so that it uses different names?

Comment: @JohnColeman I could not figure out how to write the question title, but I have explained everything in detail. I want to delete all the unwanted file keeping only last file after each iteration. If I do 100 iteration for each file I am going to use only last file i.e, the 100th one. So, other 99 are of no use. If it's not possible then I will skip iteration which will give only one output file, but I have to change the output file name as per the input file name.

Comment: Why create files that you don't want to keep? Are you sure that you can't refactor your code so that you only create the files that you want to retain? If not -- perhaps you could maintain a list of create files and iterate over it at the end, deleting what you don't want

Comment: @JohnColeman here for each iteration model creates a file, I can't do anything in that, since I don't want to enter in model code. Now if I skip iteration thing, then how to do renaming?